# ASP.NET URL validation

Tags: asp.net, iis, url

We have a custom REST handler on ASP.NET that is configured like this to handle all incoming requests:

```
<add path="*" verb="*" type="REST.RESTProtocolHandler"/>
```

However, passing it a pipe character, properly encoded or not at all, triggers a validation error that seems to come from inside ASP.NET.

Accessing `http://localhost:8080/%7c` or `http://localhost:8080/|` yields this error:

> [ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.]
>    System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars(String path) +7489125
>      System.IO.Path.Combine(String path1, String path2) +40
>      System.Web.Configuration.UserMapPath.GetPhysicalPathForPath(String path, VirtualDirectoryMapping mapping) +114
>      System.Web.Configuration.UserMapPath.GetPathConfigFilename(String siteID, VirtualPath path, String& directory, String& baseName) +72
>      System.Web.Configuration.UserMapPath.MapPath(String siteID, VirtualPath path) +30
>      System.Web.Configuration.UserMapPath.MapPath(String siteID, String path) +31
>      System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPathActual(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean permitNull) +297
>      System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPathInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean permitNull) +51
>      System.Web.CachedPathData.GetConfigPathData(String configPath) +341
>      System.Web.CachedPathData.GetVirtualPathData(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean permitPathsOutsideApp) +110
>      System.Web.HttpContext.GetFilePathData() +36
>      System.Web.HttpContext.GetConfigurationPathData() +26
>      System.Web.Configuration.RuntimeConfig.GetConfig(HttpContext context) +43
>      System.Web.Configuration.CustomErrorsSection.GetSettings(HttpContext context, Boolean canThrow) +41
>      System.Web.HttpResponse.ReportRuntimeError(Exception e, Boolean canThrow, Boolean localExecute) +101
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.FinishRequest(HttpWorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context, Exception e) +383

No userland code gets executed. Is this a configuration option somewhere? Reproduced on IIS 7 & VS Studio's 2008 devel server.

Stack Overflow seems to handle this error OK, it looks like a dynamically generated 404 MVC page gets rendered for https://stackoverflow.com/%7c.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try to intercept the exception in Global.asax file. Implement there (Global.asax.cs) this method:

```
protected void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();
    //do whatever you want with that exception
    //or get the url from the context, reformat and redirect
}
```

Comment: That is what I thought of when I first saw this post, but when I mocked it up it didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

- First you need to tinker in the
  Registry :

  http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;826437
- Restart IIS

and voila it works.

But i've made this work with IIS7 without problems, but with IIS6 I get this error (Illegal characters in path).

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar program that intercepts all and trying it with a pipe gives me the same error. I assume it has to do with IIS doing path tests (mappath) before it knows who is to handle the request. 
Your handler takes the root(meaning all calls) but i assume the way IIS does it is generic.

So I assume any or most of pathing characters that you cant use on your filesystem will fail on IIS request (GET/POST).

Maybe someone knows how to disable the IIS check. According to the error, it seems to happens even before your web.config is read, as it is trying to locate the right config?,

Maybe it is possible to use your own error page as an redirect back to your handler?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is in your stack trace.  The error is thrown on the System.IO.Path.CheckInvalidPathChars() call - this is not checking the Url, but checking the Windows file system upon which IIS sits.  It's not so much a case of the pipe character being Url illegal, but basically DOS illegal.

If you intercept the Url before IIS tries to find the matching path on the server, I expect you can deal with this error.  That probably lies in having a rewrite rule or similar to find and rewrite the Url with unwanted characters in it.

Answer (score -1):

By default IIS does not allow certain characters in the URL and considers them illegal. This is where you problem comes from - it doesn't even call the handler you have. As far as I know there is no place that you can configure which characters are accepted through UI, except for Windows Registry. I don't know why you want to use pipe, but I don't think it is good practice. As for the error page - [you can always have your own error page](http://aspnetresources.com/articles/CustomErrorPages.aspx) for any exception, so that users don't see the ugly messages.

Comment: If you look at http://stackoverflow.com/%7c, you'll see that you receive a rendered page (your username on it is a hint) so there must be a way of doing this.