# Does ASP.NET MVC Handle *#%":?<> Characters In The URL?

Tags: asp.net, url, encoding

I am new to ASP.NET MVC. I am getting an error when i use these characters - `*#%":?<>` - in URL.

My question is - Does ASP.NET MVC handle `*#%":?<>` characters in the URL?

Comment: Actually this is NOT an ASP.NET MVC question, isn't it? When the special characters are sent in a URL, they are all URLEncoded.

Answer (score 1):

[RFC 1738](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt):

> Thus, only alphanumerics, the special
>   characters "`$-_.+!*'(),`", and reserved
>   characters used for their reserved
>   purposes may be used unencoded within
>   a URL.

Of the characters you listed, only * " and - can theoretically be used unencoded.  In practice, many sites would encode all the characters you listed.

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not work, even when you encode them.

It is a stupid limitation in ASP.NET.

They do work in the querystring part though, just not the path part.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295719/asp-net-url-validation). While it does not solve the problem, at least you know you are not alone :)

Answer (score 0):

Look over here: http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/ref_urlencode.asp

If you want the chars to be transferred as plain chars, you have to encode them, as they have a meaning in urls.

Answer (score 0):

Use encode in url parameter.
Example:

```
javascript - window.location = 'path?parameter=' + encodeURIComponent(value);

Razor - @Url.Action("Action", new { parameter=Uri.EscapeUriString(@value) })"
```